# Create 2 child processes to sort words of a file using pipe

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, pipe

I want to create two child processes and distribute sorting of words from a file. e.g 1st word goes to child1 then 2nd word goes to child2 then 3rd word goes to child1 again and so on. These two child processes should run in parallel and use UNIX sort command to sort the words and store the output to a file.

The algorithm is as below

1) Child process Parser gets all the words from file and writes to a pipe

2) Child process Sorter reads from pipe and using sort with execlp function sorts the words

3) Child process Supressor removes duplicates using uniq command.

Now I want to split the sorting of words into 2 child processes, but I am not understanding how to do this.

Thanks for any inputs or help in advance.

Comment: do you want to run `sort -u input_file` command utilizing 2 CPUs?

Comment: I've noticed that GNU `sort` has `--parallel` option i.e., you can run `sort --parallel=2 -u input_file` it sorts input file running 2 sorts concurrently, removing duplicates in the output.

Comment: No @J.F.Sebastian I don't want to use any options in sort. I will have to use programming to do that. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `sort --parallel=2 -u input_file` here and you need to use pipes as an exercise then you could use a parallel *merge-sort* here. Split input file in two. Sort each half using any method you like. Merge the sorted halves removing duplicates.

Here's corresponding bash commands as an illustration:

```
mkfifo sorted_part1 sorted_part2
sort <(split -un r/1/2 input_file) >sorted_part1 & # sort 1st half
sort <(split -un r/2/2 input_file) >sorted_part2 & # sort 2nd half
sort -um sorted_part1 sorted_part2                 # merge, remove duplicates
```

In your C code you don't need to use named pipes, you could use ordinary pipes instead. And implement `split` instead of spawning the external command:

- create 4 pipes and 2 child processes
- read input file in the parent process, send lines (words) in a round-robin fashion to the child processes via corresponding pipes
- sort input and write it to output pipes in two subprocesses (just redirect input pipe to sort's stdin, sort's stdout to an output pipe, and exec `sort` command)
- read the output pipes with sorted results, merge, and remove duplicates in the parent

Example: [sort-parallel-uniq.c](https://gist.github.com/zed/7418439).

Comment: @user2575021: I've updated [the code](https://gist.github.com/zed/7418439) to make sure that the program exits with error if any of the child subprocesses fail and to improve time performance by enabling buffering for `write`s to children.